# trouble with CouchDB _rewrite handler

Tags: url-rewriting, couchdb

I am trying to use CouchDB's url rewriting capabilities, but keep getting an error:
{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"function_clause"}

I read http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Rewriting_urls and watched http://vimeo.com/20773112 and I believe I am following those guidelines (though obviously something is going wrong somewhere).

I am running CouchDB 1.2.0.

My vhost entry is:

mysite.com => /db/_design/user1505506/_rewrite

My rewrite json is:

```
   "rewrites": {
       "from": "",
       "to": "/db/_design/user1505506/index.html",
       "method": "GET"
   }
```

Any information on why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `rewrites` is always an array, so that part should look like this:

```
"rewrites": 
[
    {
       "from": "",
       "to": "/db/_design/user1505506/index.html",
       "method": "GET"
    }
]
```